# Touchpad click dosnt work in Ubuntu Netbook Remix

Tags: netbook, touchpad, ubuntu-netbook-remix

I have a MSI Wind U100+ Netbook that is duel booted with Windows XP and Ubuntu Netbook Remix.

For version:

**cat /etc/issue** gives: Ubuntu karmic (development branch) \n \l

**uname -r** gives: 2.6.30-9-generic

Everything works great except the touchpad in Ubuntu does not want to perform the 'tap-click' action. The option **is** enabled in: Preferences -> Mouse -> Touchpad. The touchpad works in Windows XP **and** when I booted into an Ubuntu Live environment via USB. So I know the hardware actually works and that it is just a config issue.

Changing the window mode from netbook remix to ubuntu desktop changes nothing.

If possible aim answer towards a new Linux user please.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok I solved my own problem =)

It can be fixed by enabling SHMConfig and then configuring the touchpad with the [gsynaptics](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/SynapticsTouchpad#shmconfig) tool.

Enable SHMConfig:

$ gksudo gedit /etc/hal/fdi/policy/shmconfig.fdi

and put this in...

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<deviceinfo version="0.2">
  <device>
    <match key="input.x11_driver" string="synaptics">
      <merge key="input.x11_options.SHMConfig" type="string">True</merge>
    </match>
  </device>
</deviceinfo>
```

Reboot your machine.

$ sudo apt-get install gsynaptics

$ sudo gsynaptics

and after changing the options located in gsynaptics it now works!